# NodeJS - How to run request-promise synchronously?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I have two functions in first I have a for loop inside that loop I'm calling the second function which has request-promise. My concern is that when the loop is executing and calling the second function **it's not waiting for request-promise to finish**, the loop is iterating next and calling the second function again. **I want first request-promise to finish then next iteration of the loop**. So how would I do that? For sake of simplicity, I'm pasting code snippets of first & second function

First Function code snippet

```js
for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    var url_ = "https://www.someurl****.com" + allUrls_ + urlLastParam + (i + 1).toString();
    console.log(allUrls_);
    console.log('getValues URL: ' + url_);
    getValues(res, url_, allUrls_)
}
```

Second Function

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

function getValues(res, url_, allUrls_) {
    let options = {
        uri: url_,
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };
    console.log('inside getValues');
    rp(options)
        .then(function ($) {
            console.log('inside getValues function request');
            $('.some-selector').map(function (i, links) {
                // my custom code
            })
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // catch errors
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return the promise from `getValues()`, then you can use `async/await` with that in your `for` loop to pause the loop for each invocation of `getValues()` and sequence them to be one after the other rather than all running at the same time:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

function getValues(res, url_, allUrls_) {
    let options = {
        uri: url_,
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };
    console.log('inside getValues');
    return rp(options).then(function($) {               // return promise here
        console.log('inside getValues function request');
```

cheerio here
            $('.some-selector').map(function (i, links) {
                // my custom code
            })
            return something;                      // presumably return something here
        });
    }

```
async function process() {
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            var url_ = "https://www.someurl****.com" + allUrls_ + urlLastParam + (i + 1).toString();
            console.log(allUrls_);
            console.log('getValues URL: ' + url_);
            let value = await getValues(res, url_, allUrls_);     // await here
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            // handle any error that occurred in getValues()
        }
    }
}
```

FYI, `$('.some-selector')` will not work the way you had it in this code.  `$` was your HTML.  You have to first load the html content into cheerio before you can do that (which I added to my answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked but it's not scraping more than 2 pages IDK why. but thanks anyway.

Comment: @AjayKumar - Well, perhaps your `for` loop isn't quite doing what it should with different URLs.  I don't know what you're trying to do there and you don't have real URLs there so I can't really look at it.

Comment: Thanks! for the quick reply, here is my project link https://github.com/AjayKrP/scraper Have a look

Comment: @AjayKumar - OK, I didn't realize you were already running `cheerio.load()` as a transform option in request-promise.  You can remove the `cheerio.load()` I added.  I will update my answer.

Comment: @AjayKumar - As far as only processing 2 pages, you'll just have to debug that.  Start with how many links `getAllUrls()` gets.  Then, see how many times `getPageUrlAndLength()` gets called in the `allUrls.forEach()` loop.  Then, see how many times `getValues()` is called inside of `process()` and so on.  You should be able to follow the flow and see where it's not doing what you expect.